# Duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 under Xcode in react native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, xcode, react-native

duplicate symbol '_fsQueue' in:
/Users/iTech/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/billingcalculatorshreejicode-exzozodcmqezdscmibmkfzyrvmvc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-blob-util/libreact-native-blob-util.a(ReactNativeBlobUtil.o)
/Users/iTech/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/billingcalculatorshreejicode-exzozodcmqezdscmibmkfzyrvmvc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/rn-fetch-blob/librn-fetch-blob.a(RNFetchBlob.o)
duplicate symbol '_commonTaskQueue' in:
/Users/iTech/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/billingcalculatorshreejicode-exzozodcmqezdscmibmkfzyrvmvc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-blob-util/libreact-native-blob-util.a(ReactNativeBlobUtil.o)
/Users/iTech/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/billingcalculatorshreejicode-exzozodcmqezdscmibmkfzyrvmvc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/rn-fetch-blob/librn-fetch-blob.a(RNFetchBlob.o)
duplicate symbol '_fileStreams' in:
/Users/iTech/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/billingcalculatorshreejicode-exzozodcmqezdscmibmkfzyrvmvc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-blob-util/libreact-native-blob-util.a(ReactNativeBlobUtilFS.o)
/Users/iTech/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/billingcalculatorshreejicode-exzozodcmqezdscmibmkfzyrvmvc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/rn-fetch-blob/librn-fetch-blob.a(RNFetchBlobFS.o)
duplicate symbol '_expirationTable' in:
/Users/iTech/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/billingcalculatorshreejicode-exzozodcmqezdscmibmkfzyrvmvc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-blob-util/libreact-native-blob-util.a(ReactNativeBlobUtilNetwork.o)
/Users/iTech/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/billingcalculatorshreejicode-exzozodcmqezdscmibmkfzyrvmvc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/rn-fetch-blob/librn-fetch-blob.a(RNFetchBlobNetwork.o)
ld: 4 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

## clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imVJ5.jpg)

## error photo show above

Comment: i think you use both react-native-blob-util and rn-fetch-blob use single one best recommendation react-native-blob-util

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i remove unused react-native-blob-util and error resolved